# Postgresql C-function, don't load external dll file

Tags: c, database, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, dll

I write my dll files in visual studio 2010.

The dll file (name fservice.dll), which has an external function, code write in c++ (VS2010, I have dll and lib files)

```
char * convert(char *)
```

Dll file witch has c-function, who exports and imports to postgresql:

```
typedef char* (__cdecl *MYPROC)(char * value); 

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(transform);

Datum
transform (PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  HINSTANCE hinstLib= LoadLibrary("fservice.dll"); 
  char * pointer;
  text *t = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);

  if (hinstLib != NULL) 
  { 

      ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "convert");
      pointer=ProcAdd("text");
      FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
  }

  /*
   * code 
   */

  PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(new_t);
}
```

I have a problem because, mod is doesn't exists. Path to dll file I check before write.
Compile this c-function, and when i debug i saw it  HINSTANCE hinstLib it wasn't created. It wasn't NULL or any value, It wasn't exist. Finally my c-function doesn't use my function form external dll.

**How load dll and use my external function ?**

My external function form dll and LoadLibrary() is not called by dll program with called by Postgresql, Why?

Comment: Can you debug the LoadLibrary and checks if the file is in the right location for the project to locate it?

Comment: I traded [tag:visual-studio-2010] for [tag:c++], because this is [tag:c] only and gives an additional hint for people filtering by tag.

Comment: LoadLibrary() is not called by dll program with called by Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

this may be a simple answer, but what I don't see is a create function call.  It would be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE C AS
'/path/to/dll', 'transform';
```

Until you create the function, PostgreSQL doesn't know to dynamically load the dll....